# how to oatuh authentication on vimeo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth

I am doing oatuh authentication on vimeo using **gtm oauth framework**. My problem is when i successfully get access token using gtmo framework  then i give call to below function to get video json value for vimeo but i am getting this error:

> {"generated_in":"0.0046","stat":"fail","err":{"code":"401","expl":"The oauth_signature passed was not valid.","msg":"Invalid signature"}}

Actualy the problem is when i getting signature value from auth object then their is no signature parameter exist in auth object. Kindly guide me where i am doing mistake:

```
- (void) fetchNetwork:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth
{
    NSLog(@"auth access token %@",auth.accessToken);
      NSLog(@"auth access token %@",auth.token);
    NSLog(@"auth consumer key %@",auth.consumerKey);
    NSLog(@"auth  token%@",auth.token);
    NSLog(@"realm %@",auth.realm);
    NSLog(@"auth  version %@",auth.version);
    NSLog(@"auth  signature method %@",auth.signatureMethod);
    NSLog(@"auth  time stamp%@",auth.timestamp);
    NSLog(@"auth  nonce %@",auth.nonce);


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.search&oauth_consumer_key=%@&oauth_nonce=%@&oauth_signature_method=%@&oauth_timestamp=%@&oauth_version=%@&oauth_signature=%@&query=amirkhan",auth.consumerKey,auth.nonce,auth.signatureMethod,auth.timestamp,auth.version,@""]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

                   [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

     NSLog(@"response string:%@",request);
    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:nil];
     NSLog(@"response string:%@",responseData);
    NSString *strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response string:%@",strResponse);
    NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);

    }
```

Comment: HI, Did you found answer for this. I am also having same problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I might be too late for response.
But you need to attach the authenticated signature along with every request like this

[signedAuth authorizeRequest:request];

where signedAuth is the instance of GTMOAuthAuthentication got back after authentication